# Gstreamer Elements could not be linked

Tags: gstreamer

I'm new to GStreamer, I followed the [Basic tutorial 2 on GStreamer website](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html?gi-language=c) and try to make it work with local mp4 file.
My problem is that I can't link "uridecodebin" and "autovideosink", here is my related code :

```
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", "source");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !sink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return -1;
  }

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
  if (gst_element_link (source, sink) != TRUE) {
      g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
      gst_object_unref (pipeline);
      return -1;
  }
```

It always return false with `gst_element_link (source, sink)`, but it worked well if I simply use `gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file://MyPathToVideo/test.mp4 ! autovideosink` command, what am I doing wrong?

Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `gst_parse_launch()` and giving it your pipeline. It is shorter this way. And I believe it takes care of some particularities in your case.

The main issue your approach is not working is that `uridecodebin` does not expose any pads because at that point in time it does not know anything about your MP4 file. So it can contain audio, video, both - or whatever. The correct approach is to implement delayed linking.

So instead of linking it directly you implement the `pad-added` signal on `uridecodebin`:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstelement.html?gi-language=c#GstElement::pad-added

Then you start the pipeline with the elements disconnected.

This `pad-added` signal is triggered when `uridecodebin` has scanned your media file and exposes pads which can be linked. In case it is your video pad you can connect it to the `autovideosink`.

`gst_parse_launch()` if I'm not mistaken will take of this automatically for you (at least that is what `gst-lauch-1.0` is doing - not sure if that specific functionality moved to that API as well).

P.S. You jumped the gun. Tutorial 2 does not use `uridecodebin` but more basic elements. Tutorial 3 will cover dynamic pipelines.

Comment: Thanks! I truly rushd it too much. my simple example works now! 
BTW, I'm currently working on a existed project which used `gst_parse_launch` and `filesrc location=/home/root/test.mp4 ! decodebin  ! qvconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, framerate=1/1 ! queue ! appsink name=cameraFrameSink ` as status, is it possible to change file location dynamically instead of creating a new pipeline?

Comment: It sure is, question is what will happen downstream as the media could be completely different. Perhaps you want to look at `multifilesrc`.